# Can I write something like my own version of ID3 Tags to MP3s?

Tags: mp3, computer-science, id3

Reference: http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_overview

It seems as though ID3 Tags just don't do all the things I want it to do. I was thinking I could write information to the comments and use the comments field as my storage of a better data structure, but that's pretty hacky. I wanted to find out, in a general sense, what directions I have available to me. Can I write something like an ID3 tag to a file or is it built into what an MP3 is?

If no, does this mean other than storing a mapping to files outside of the file I have to live inside the ID3 fields?

If yes, can I do this to any file? Is there something special about MP3s that allows you to write arbitrary meta data or could I do this with WAV files as well.

I know that for some people this is probably the basics of how files work, so I apologize if it's obvious.

Thanks!

UPDATE: It seems like using npm groove I an write any metadata field I want to the file. Does this mean that ID3 is just a standard of metadata fields and anyone can write any [key, value] metadata information to any file? Because that's what it seems like, and that's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can write any data AROUND your files. This kind of metadata around MP3 music data is called ID3. ID3 is available for [other formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Non-MP3-implementation_and_alternatives) too.

The main problem that you will run into: You have to be sure that your devices reading such files are capable to interpret your metadata. Simple example: If you would write an ID3-Tag around a JPG-File, you can be (almost) sure, that no 3rd party program or device will read this metadata. Most of the graphics program will not even read the JPG-picture-part anymore, because no one would expect an ID3-Tag around an JPG file. (This kind of metadata would be added in a EXIF-Tag).

As long as you add an ID3-Tag to MP3 music files, you can add whatever you want. In addition to all the existing [standard tags](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_overview) you can even add your own [private frames](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Private_frame) with your very specific informations. If like to add the 'eye color of the lead singer' in your own specifc ID3 tag, feel free to do that.